# Error missing } and unreachable break after return

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

So The code below when run gives me the same output twice. I only need it to give me one output. It would be very helpful if You guys could help me solve this issue. This might be a stupid question since I'm new to java script.

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
    var review;
     switch(movie.toUpperCase()){
        case 'Matrix'.toUpperCase():
            review = console.log("Good trip out");
        break;
        case 'Princess Bride'.toUpperCase():
            review = console.log("awesome date night movie");
        break;
        case 'Welcome to America'.toUpperCase():
            review = console.log("Amjad's favorite");
        break;
        case 'Remember the Titans'.toUpperCase():
            review = console.log("love the sports");
        break;
        case "Why do I look like i'm 12?".toUpperCase():
            review = console.log("The Ryan and Zach story");
        break;
        case 'Fighting Kangaroos in the wild'.toUpperCase():
            review = console.log("Token Australian movie for Leng");
        break;
        default:
            review = console.log("I don't Know");
            break;
    }
    return review;
};
getReview("matrix");
```

output:

```
Good trip out
good trip out
```

and if the code is

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
    var review;
     switch(movie.toUpperCase()){
        case 'Matrix'.toUpperCase():
            return("Good trip out");
        break;
        case 'Princess Bride'.toUpperCase():
            return("awesome date night movie");
        break;
        case 'Welcome to America'.toUpperCase():
            return("Amjad's favorite");
        break;
        case 'Remember the Titans'.toUpperCase():
            return("love the sports");
        break;
        case "Why do I look like i'm 12?".toUpperCase():
            return("The Ryan and Zach story");
        break;
        case 'Fighting Kangaroos in the wild'.toUpperCase():
            return("Token Australian movie for Leng");
        break;
        default:
            return("I don't Know");
            break;
    }


getReview("matrix");
```

the output is
Error missing }
and unreachable break after return
What do both need to work and only return one output not two.

Comment: Is there a reason you are programmatically uppercasing the hard coded string literals within the `switch` statement rather than just making them uppercase literals to begin with? Depending on how many times you perform the `switch` statement, it could become very expensive to do the uppercase operations over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing the }; to end the function. The unreachable break after return is irrelevant the code below should work. Don't mind the Unreachable break after return.

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
        var review;
         switch(movie.toUpperCase()){
            case 'Matrix'.toUpperCase():
                return("Good trip out");
            break;
            case 'Princess Bride'.toUpperCase():
                return("awesome date night movie");
            break;
            case 'Welcome to America'.toUpperCase():
                return("Amjad's favorite");
            break;
            case 'Remember the Titans'.toUpperCase():
                return("love the sports");
            break;
            case "Why do I look like i'm 12?".toUpperCase():
                return("The Ryan and Zach story");
            break;
            case 'Fighting Kangaroos in the wild'.toUpperCase():
                return("Token Australian movie for Leng");
            break;
            default:
                return("I don't Know");
                break;
        }

    };
    getReview("matrix");
```

output:

```
"Good trip out"
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I needed. Sorry for the dumb mistake and thanks for fast response!!

Comment: Or just remove all of the "break"(s).

Comment: That would work too but the code is good now, if all you want is it too return the strings. But you could remove the breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the double output is because of this form:

```
review = console.log("Good trip out");
```

The console.log call is printing the string to the console. You then assign the result of console.log to review, which appears to be the string it printed.

Then, when you run `getReview('Matrix')` on the console, the console will automatically print the return value - which was the string which got printed.

Thus, the two outputs.